# Sort and count sql results with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sql table column name `referrer` and I want to query the table to get every `referrer` and count duplicates, display each unique `referrer` and the number of times each unique `referrer` is recorded in the table with php. I'm a beginner with sql and php so any help in the right direction would be great :)

```
$ref=$icdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM url_log WHERE u = '".$dom."'");
```

Comment: `select referrer, count(*) from url_log where ... group by referrer order by 2 desc`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function, `count()` in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to find duplicates is to use GROUP BY to generate a frequency table.

```
SELECT count(1) AS frequency, referrer 
FROM url_log
WHERE u = '".$dom."'
GROUP BY referrer
ORDER BY frequency DESC;
```

This gives you one row per referrer and the number of times that referrer appears in the table, sorted by most frequent referrers.

Comment: `foreach ($ref as $details) {
   echo $details['referrer']."</td><td>".$details['frequency']."</td>";
}`

gives me: 22hh

How do I print the array correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT referrer, count(*) as counter FROM url_log GROUP BY referrer
```